# JavaScript: Assigning Methods in Object Literal

Tags: javascript, object

I am trying to set a method in an object literal. The method is an external function. I thought that the following would work:

```
    //  Global Data & Function
    var message='global';
    function sayit() {
        alert(this.message);
    }

    var a={
        message: "apple",
        doit: sayit
    }
```

or even

```
    var b={
        message: "banana",
        doit: sayit.bind(this)
    }
```

but both of them fail.

It seems that the only way to add a method is either:

```
    a.doit=sayit;
```

or

```
    var a={
        message: "apple",
        doit: function() {
            sayit();
        }
    }
```

Is there a more direct way to assign a function as a method?

Thanks

Comment: you first attempt should work fine, no need for complicated solutions. what is error message you get when you try to run it?

Comment: How are you calling it, and which message did you expect it to alert?

Comment: `a.doit=sayit;` is definitively no different from `a = {doit:sayit};`

Comment: [Can't reproduce](http://jsfiddle.net/9krf54v0/).

Comment: You are probably not calling the method correctly. The value of `this` depends on how the function is **called**. [Learn more about `this`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this).

Comment: `sayIt` should be on the prototype of the class and the object should be an instance of that class

Comment: @BillPull: There is no reason for using constructors if a single object is needed. Also completely irrelevant to the issue at hand.

Comment: @FelixKling I know this little snippet is probably just an example of what the real problem looks like so I guess for the immediate question it is irrelevant but I thought it worth mentioning in case they aren't familiar with classes and inheritance in JS. Who knows maybe the actual problem is better suited to having an actual class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you calling the function by the right name, it should be like this:

```
//  Global Data & Function
    var message = 'global';
    function sayit() {
        alert(this.message);
    }
    var a = {
        message: "apple",
        doit: sayit
    }

    a.doit();
```

Comment: Your’re correct, of course. The error was a typo in my calling the function. Thanks